# Does the 4e Feat Diabolic Soul only replace Infernal Wrath after receiving a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

The way I currently understand it, the feat appears to imply that the transformation power replaces infernal wrath only after receiving a critical hit. Am I correct in this? The relevant piece of the description is below.

> Whenever you take a critical hit, you gain a +2 feat bonus to attack rolls against that enemy until the end of the encounter. In addition, you replace infernal wrath with diabolic transformation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, these are two separate effects:

- You replace your infernal wrath with diabolic transformation (all the time as soon as you take the feat, regardless of if you have been critted)
- You gain +2 to attack rolls after being critically hit